# How to create dynamic nested amp accordion iterate issue

Tags: amp-html, amp-list

> I have to create a dynamic accordion in Google AMP pages using Ajax API call.
> Below is the response I am getting from API

```
{
topics: [
{
  title: "Fashion",
  slug: "fashion",
  id: 3,
  topic_icon:
    "https://img-static.popxo.com/manual-uploads/app_category_icons/fashion_category_ic.png",
  description:
    `"Do you eat, sleep and breathe fashion? 'Coz we do!\n` +
    'High street labels to local markets, to lesser-known online brands, we know where to find the trendiest stuff and how to style it right!"',
  sort_index: 1,
  sub_categories: [
    {
      title: "Latest Trends: Western",
      slug: "western-wear",
      id: 70,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: "Latest Trends: Western",
      further_sub_categories: [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]],
    },
    {
      title: "DIY Fashion",
      slug: "diy",
      id: 68,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [],
    },
    {
      title: "Accessories",
      slug: "accessories",
      id: 66,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [[Object], [Object], [Object]],
    },
    {
      title: "Latest Trends: Indian",
      slug: "indian-wear",
      id: 69,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [[Object]],
    },
    {
      title: "Celebrity Style",
      slug: "celeb-fashion",
      id: 67,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [],
    },
  ],
},
{
  title: "Beauty",
  slug: "beauty",
  id: 1,
  topic_icon:
    "https://img-static.popxo.com/manual-uploads/app_category_icons/beauty_category_ic.png",
  description:
    '"Conquer the world, one red lipstick at a time!\n' +
    `Are you looking for reliable makeup reviews? Tired of searching the internet for solutions to your beauty woes and coming up with nothing? Look no further! We've got expert answers to all your beauty problems in one place!"`,
  sort_index: 2,
  sub_categories: [
    {
      title: "Latest Trends: Western",
      slug: "western-wear",
      id: 70,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: "Latest Trends: Western",
      further_sub_categories: [[Object], [Object], [Object], [Object]],
    },
    {
      title: "DIY Fashion",
      slug: "diy",
      id: 68,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [],
    },
    {
      title: "Accessories",
      slug: "accessories",
      id: 66,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [[Object], [Object], [Object]],
    },
    {
      title: "Latest Trends: Indian",
      slug: "indian-wear",
      id: 69,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [[Object]],
    },
    {
      title: "Celebrity Style",
      slug: "celeb-fashion",
      id: 67,
      main_category_slug: "fashion",
      description: null,
      further_sub_categories: [],
    },
  ],
},
```

];
}

Code in AMP HTML

```
{{~it.hamburgerData.topics :value:index}}
<amp-accordion expand-single-section>
  <section>
    <h2>{{=value.title}}</h2>
    <amp-list id="myList" src="{{=value.sub_categories}}" [is-layout-container]="true" binding="no">
      <template type="amp-mustache">
        <div>{{title}}</div>
      </template>
    </amp-list>
  </section>
</amp-accordion>
{{~}}
```

I want to create a dynamic hamburger menu in which I am using AMP accordion the **topic** array will be accordion value and **sub_categories** is a nested array for submenu. The accordion works properly but the amp-list tag does not work .someone please help me with this dynamic accordion or suggests some better way of implementing

Comment: What is the error in the browser console? You have invalid JSON, check your JSON.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov I cannot change my JSON object because it is coming from API. I Know JSON is not as per the amp-list format. Can you please suggest to me how I should handle this condition so that it can work

Comment: 1). Check your JSON in this example, it looks like there are missing closing brackets (`]; }`). 2). See my working example: https://codepen.io/alexandr-kazakov/pen/WNGzLvX If your JSON will not work, then I see this option: on the backend, JSON should be converted to a valid format(before it gets into the amp-list)

Comment: It looks like you have either a JSON problem or a syntax problem. I don't think this is a problem with amp-accordion.

Comment: @AlexandrKazakov I cannot change API JSON response. how do I format the data in the frontend as per the AMP list in the state? please suggested

Comment: If the JSON in the response is invalid, then most likely nothing can be done, it will not be displayed in the amp-list. You need to write a middleware on the backend, which will fix JSON and a valid JSON will be sent to the frontend. In any case, I'll think about it again today. In your question, add a link(for a GET request) to your JSON, I'll try it myself.